# How to decode Bitmap from MediaStore using inSampleSize() and inJustDecodeBounds()

Tags: android, bitmap, mediastore

I need to decode image from MediaStore, but before doing this load smaller one using inSampleSize() option. MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap() does not provides any options for decoding. So I get to know how to read image size, and the apply inSampleSize() for image provided by MediaStore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
InputStream stream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
...
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                stream,
                null,
                options
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this from official site: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.